# How to delete repo on AWS Cloud9?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

Recently started working with AWS Cloud9 and ran into problem how to delete/remove local repository from a list.

GUI allows many actions by click, but remove repository is not one of them.

How do i remove repository from sourcecontrol panel?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is treating Cloud9 as regular terminal.

To remove repository you need to run commands:

```
rm -rf your-repository/.git
```

And if you would like to clean up the files:

```
rm -rf your-repository
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found the commands below helpful in the clean up process

list command;
aws cloudformation list-stacks

delete command;
aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name

list crawlers command;
aws glue get-crawlers

delete crawlers command;
aws glue delete-crawler --name

list command;
aws glue get-jobs

delete command;
aws glue delete-job --job-name

list command;
aws iam list-users

delete command;
aws iam delete-user --user-name

list command;
aws s3 ls

delete command;
aws s3 rb s3:// --force

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).